# Question about inverse releationship in Core Data

Tags: iphone, core-data

HI

I am just starting to learn Core Data and one part that confuses me is the inverse relationship. Lets say that I have a entitiy named Photo and one enitity named Photograph, just as in the Stanford course. A photograph has a one to many relationship to photo, and one photo belongs to one photograph.

My question is (I know SQL) is what are the inverse relationships I have to make? This probably has to do with primary/foreign key however I do not understand what inverse relationship does?

Thanks for your time:=)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[An inverse relationship](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/Articles/cdRelationships.html) maintains data integrity when changes are made to instances of an entity:

> You should typically model
>   relationships in both directions, and
>   specify the inverse relationships
>   appropriately. Core Data uses this
>   information to ensure the consistency
>   of the object graph if a change is
>   made (see “[Manipulating Relationships
>   and Object Graph Integrity”](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/Articles/cdRelationships.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40001857-SW3)). For a
>   discussion of some of the reasons why
>   you might want to not model a
>   relationship in both directions, and
>   some of the problems that might arise
>   if you don’t, see “[Unidirectional
>   Relationships](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/Articles/cdRelationships.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40001857-SW6).”